# Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.' in database '' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have my SQL DB which have maximum size of 10 GB(express edition) and currently it has "2864.35 MB" size available. which giving error on  changing column datatype of a column 'NAME' from `nvarchar(1000)` to `nvarchar(400)`.
this column don't require so much space and after this i want to apply non clustered index on it . ...
Error coming is -

> "Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.' in database '' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. 
>   Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, 
>   or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup."

I have sql express edition with size 2012 (max limit of 10 GB).
I have googled so much but nothing working in my solution...

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: **setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup** - have you tried that?

Comment: Ya, i have tried this for primary file group.it has "By 1048576 MB,Unlimited" . but not working.giving same error.

Comment: And what would be the size of DB if currently it's **2.8GB** and `growth by` is **1024GB**? Would it fit **10GB** limit?

Comment: i am surprise when i am seeing size of my db in properties it's showing 40309.44 MB (arround 39 GB) and space available "2864.35 MB" (2.79 GB) .whats going on ? . Max size on express edition is 10 GB. than whats wrong here .... it's gone out of my understanding ...

Comment: Add screenshot of `Files` tab from DB properties dialog. And, I suppose you should migrate this question to dba.stackexchange

Comment: hey thanx , i googled and try very much . i seen a problem  that before performing operation that i told above  its's total size is 10 Gb(max limit) and around 8 GB is free.But when i performing this modification operation My drive in which sql installed become full .it has acquire 44 GB space and i getting this error which i told above. have you any idea why this dude ?

Comment: Add screenshot of your settings.